# Generate SQLAlchemy models from Pydantic models

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, pydantic, sqlmodel

So I have this large JSON dataset with a huge number of properties (as well as nested objects). I have used `datamodel-code-generator` to build pydantic models. The JSON data has been imported into pydantic models (with nested models).

Now I need to push them into the database.

How can I automatically generate SQLAlchemy/SQLModel (or any other ORM) model definition classes from pydantic models?

Note: SQLModel and Pydantic seem to have similar syntax for model definition, so I guess I could copy-paste the pydantic models and edit as necessary. But I'm not that familiar with SQLModel yet. I was wondering if there was an automated way to do this.

Comment: An automated way to generate database schemas with a "huge number of properties" sounds like a terrible idea, to be honest. Yes, `SQLModel` inherits from `BaseModel`, so you could just mindlessly replace that and add the `table=True` argument, but I would suggest taking a closer look at them first. Especially relationships usually require some attention. In general I would say, if you care so little about the schemas that you are willing to automatically generate them, maybe you should just use a schemaless database to begin with.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I know that. Obviously the "automated technique" will do 80% of the work, and remaining will have to be taken care of manually. Yes, the relationships will have their own tables (pydantic extracts those related objects into different models, which helps a lot). NOSQL is not an option unfortunately. The raw JSON data I'm dealing with can go up to 330KB in size per entity, and has a lot of invalid attributes like "TAX RATE (1)", "ADDL_PROP-ID". Each of the entities have hundreds of such properties, and most entities contain a Russian doll of dependent entities.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg With Pydantic I was able to convert the mess into neat little discrete python objects (with some manual tweaking of course). Now I want to import this data into the database without recreating SQL model classes. Obviously the table relationships will have to be manually defined, but for the 95% of the simple properties I need to automate. For the record, the consumer end of this data will be built with Asp.net and entity framework core. Hence the DDL will be a one time job.

Comment: I see, this was not clear to me from the way you phrased the question initially. Would you mind providing a highly reduced/simplified example (ideally including a relationship) of two or three Pydantic models you ended up with, which you wish to turn into database schemas? Also, how many models have you ended up with actually (approximately)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several python packages that add an ORM layer on top of Pydantic.

Pynocular - supports pgsql only

pydbantic - lightweight ORM on top of pydantic models.

SQLModel - from the author of FastAPI. I'd chosen to go with sqlmodel as it provides the power of SQLAlchemy under the hood.